# Apache2 no interpreta el framework de php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

llevo desde hace no mucho empezando en el uso de VPS y máquinas Ubuntu y GNU/Linux para mantener mis webs, recientemente he estado usando el framework de php laravel, la cosa es que no logro averiguar el porqué no me detecta dicho script de php, en hostings normales (no siendo VPS) me los reconoce perfectamente y se inicia de manera correcta el instalador de Laravel.

Supongo que tendré algo mal configurado o no habré instalado alguna extensión de php, tengo actualmente instalado Mysql y phpmyadmin para la gestión de las BD.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Edit:

[image: Captura del resultado directo en la web]

error.log en /var/log/apache2

````
[Wed Aug 31 16:53:32.345880 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 72225] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Aug 31 16:53:32.459445 2022] [so:warn] [pid 72578] AH01574: module php_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 16:53:32.479672 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 72579] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 31 16:53:32.479689 2022] [core:notice] [pid 72579] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Aug 31 16:53:43.081742 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 72582] [client 162.158.129.48:27648] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/lafama/storage/framework/views/ee1ed3c7bdbd2dbfeb142b3fed10c79b0d34ea5e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()\n#1 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(187): file_put_contents()\n#2 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(163): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put()\n#3 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(55): Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile()\n#4 /var/www/lafama/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()\n#5 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Facade\\Ignition...PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/lafama/storage/framework/views/ee1ed3c7bdbd2dbfeb142b3fed10c79b0d34ea5e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:187\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()\n#1 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(187): file_put_contents()\n#2 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(163): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put()\n#3 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(55): Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile()\n#4 /var/www/lafama/vendor/facade/ignition/src/Views/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(37): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get()\n#5 /var/www/lafama/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(139): Facade\\Ignition...', referer: https://lafamadventures.cf/
[Wed Aug 31 16:54:38.820530 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 72579] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Aug 31 16:54:38.929567 2022] [so:warn] [pid 72611] AH01574: module php_module is already loaded, skipping
[Wed Aug 31 16:54:38.942736 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 72612] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 31 16:54:38.942755 2022] [core:notice] [pid 72612] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'```
````

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Algún error en los logs de PHP?

Comment: Buenas, yo diría que si, me aparece el error `Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents`

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Pon un fragmento más completo de los logs EN la pregunta, por favor

Comment: ¡Gracias por el consejo! Lo tendré en cuenta para futuras ocasiones, como me has sugerido, ya he puesto el log de lo que me sale en errores.

Comment: `Permission denied` Revisa si el apache está en el mismo grupo que la carpeta donde tienes la aplicación. Aquí unas recomendaciones adicionales sobre cómo mejorar la calidad de las preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Buenas, la carpeta www y la del dominio la posee root, aunque todos los archivos de dentro las posee el grupo del usuario ubuntu, ya que subí los archivos por sftp.

Comment: Buenas , ¿tienes apache configurado correctamente  con laravel? Laravel usa su propio .htaccess , ¿esta subido al directorio?  Laravel también requiere que  mod_rewrite este habilitado en apache para el embellecimiento de URLS.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas parece que no tienes habilitado el embellecimiento de url que laravel necesita para mostrar correctamente las rutas.

Revise que tiene el modulo de re-escritura de urls en apache

```
apachectl -M
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de no tenerlo puedes habilitarlo con :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Una vez añadido el modulo reinicia apache para actualizar los cambios.